# Converting bar-codes to specific format using IF, FIND & MID function of excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel I have a number of columns containing characters of different types such as:

```
WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14 
WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S8-P1 
WS-S5-N-L1-C29-V-U16-S6-P6
```

I want to convert these to 8 characters using the following rules:

- keep only the last three segments
- remove the U and add prefix 0 where appropriate
- remove S and add prefix 0 where appropriate
- remove P and add prefix 0 where appropriate

For example:

- `WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14` convert to `05-09-14`
- `WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S8-P1` convert to `05-08-01`
- `WS-S5-N-L1-C29-V-U16-S6-P6` convert to `16-06-06`

I believe there is a way to use `IF`, `FIND` & `MID` function to convert these in Excel but don't know how to start. Any help will be much appreciated.

### Update

Just finally, I wanted to convert this into 13 characters if possible for example:

- WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14    convert to S1-F-05-09-14
- WS-S5-N-L2-C31-D-U5-S8-P1 convert to N2-D-05-08-01
- WS-S5-N-L1-C29-V-U16-S6-P6    conver to N1-V-16-06-06

Comment: Are the strings always off the same length?

Comment: @Kevin: no, see "U5" vs "U16"

Comment: Strings are of different length and I've used the following formula which returns "05" from WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14. But how do I return "05-09-14"?


=IF(MID(E13,FIND("-U",E13)+3,1)="-","0"&MID(E13,FIND("-U",E13)+2,1),MID(E13,FIND("-U",E13)+2,2))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @ygaft pointed out, it's possible, but going to be long with standard Excel functions.

I use free [RegEx Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) add-in in situation like that, using a regular expression you can achieve it easier.

The formula:
`=RegExReplace(RegExReplace(A1,".*U([0-9]+)-S([0-9]+)-P([0-9]+)","0$1-0$2-0$3"),"0([0-9]{2})","$1")`

How it works:

- inner function:

  - `A1`: from content of A1 cell
  - `".*U([0-9]+)-S([0-9]+)-P([0-9]+)"` look for a pattern "...U#-S#-P#" where "#" represents one or more numbers and remembers the numbers (brackets create reference groups)
  - `"0$1-0$2-0$3"` merges the numbers found in previous step, adding leading 0 to all of them.
- outer function:

  - `RegExReplace(...)` - works with results of inner function
  - `"0([0-9]{2})"` - looks for 0 followed by two digits (= cases where leading 0 is not necessary)
  - `"$1"` - keeps only the two digits, dropping leading 0 (only in cases which were matched in previous step)

[image]

You can also see more explanation on the regular expressions online:

- first step: https://regex101.com/r/4W4dWw/1
- second step: https://regex101.com/r/mA8lGs/1

*Note: I'm not affiliated in any way with that add-in, just use it as it makes my life easier.*

### Update

You can use this formula for your 13 character code:
`=RegExReplace(RegExReplace(A3,".*-([A-Z])-[A-Z]([0-9]).*-([A-Z])-U([0-9]+)-S([0-9]+)-P([0-9]+)","$1$2-$3-0$4-0$5-0$6"),"0([0-9]{2})","$1")`

Comment: That's a great add-in to use. Worked perfectly. Just finally, I wanted to convert this into 13 characters if possible for example:

* WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14 convert to   S1-F-05-09-14

* WS-S5-N-L2-C31-D-U5-S8-P1 convert to   N2-D-05-08-01

* WS-S5-N-L1-C29-V-U16-S6-P6 convert to    N1-V-16-06-06

Comment: how do you mean 13 characters? Please update your question and I'll update my answer

Comment: Basically converting:
• WS-S5-S-L1-C31-F-U5-S9-P14 to   S1-F-05-09-14

• WS-S5-N-L2-C31-D-U5-S8-P1  to   N2-D-05-08-01

• WS-S5-N-L1-C29-V-U16-S6-P6  to   N1-V-16-06-06

So using the 7th, 10th, 15,16 and 17th character

Answer (score 5):

Pretty ugly,
but you can achieve it by the following, it assumes that your working data is in column A:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),FIND("-",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),1)-1),"00")&"-"&TEXT(MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),FIND("-",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),1)+2,(FIND("P",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),1)-2-FIND("S",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),1))),"00")&"-"&TEXT(RIGHT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)))-FIND("P",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)),1)),"00")
```

Comment: great technique used but code runs a bit lengthy.

Comment: to make it shorter, you can add helper column with that function:
'=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("U",A1,1)' and then refer to that column instead all that piece of code